# how to spark use overwrite jdbc connect open kerberos hive?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hive, kerberos

**environment**：original hadoop；open kerberos hive；depoly-mode:yanr-clint；every haoop node put certificate；
**process**：overwrite spark jdbcsource,spark use this souce connect hive,before connect have auth,and auth succeed,but when executor execute connect have exception:

```
sqlexception:could not open client for any of server uri is zookeeper:null
```

**question**:how to slove this error,i have try set UserGroupInformation and auth succeed, and set spark javaextraoption but not take effect

Answer (score 0):

this is auth code:

```
   public static void  initkerberos() {

        try {
            String configPath = "/opt/hbaseConfig/tx/"+krbConfig;
            String keytabPath = "/opt/hbaseConfig/tx/"+krbKeytab;

            System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", configPath);
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.set("hadoop.security.authentication", "kerberos");

            UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(conf);
            UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(krbUser, keytabPath);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            logger.error("Kerberos 验证失败", e);

        }

    }
```